# What version of Battlefield 4 do I need for all the single-player action?

Tags: battlefield-4

I'm looking to buy Battlefield 4, but my main interest is only in single-player campaign. Origin lists 3 versions of Battlefield 4 for sale:

[image]

[Source](https://www.origin.com/en-us/store/buy/battlefield-4/pc-download/base-game/standard-edition)

It seems that there's a lot of additional content for multiplayer, but I don't really care too much about that. How do I get the best single-player campaign goods out of Battlefield 4, which version should I buy?

Comment: Just the stock game. Everything is for Multiplayer. Premium (more stuff for MP), China Rising (MP DLC), Battlepacks (MP again)

Comment: Ill turn it into an answer in a sec...

Comment: Also, be careful if you end up buying SP only and want to play MP. I don't own BF4 so I don't know, but on BF3, (in Australia) it costs ~$30. Premium + Game costs ~$70. But if you goto buy Premium alone after the game, it's ~$70 alone. They make you pay more, so be careful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get the most out of Single Player, you don't need anything but the stock game.

### BF4: Game

Comes with original Single Player campaign, basic Multiplayer (Stock gamemodes, guns, etc.)

You must pay for all current and future DLC's unless you buy Premium.
Doesn't come with Premium items (such as some guns)

### BF4: China Rising

[**Page**](http://www.battlefield.com/au/battlefield-4/expansion-packs/china-rising)

Adds 4 new multiplayer maps.
Air Superiority multiplayer Game Mode.
New multiplayer vehicles.

### BF4: Premium

[**Page**](http://www.battlefield.com/au/battlefield-4/premium)

Gives all future DLC's (including current **China Rising**) and those 12 Battlepacks.

---

If your planning on playing Multiplayer **AT ALL** I suggest getting the Premium package.
I did so for BF3 and it adds SO much to the game.
It's up to you though. The game was made for Multiplayer, but Singleplayer only, then just get the stock game, you are literally wasting your money otherwise.

Comment: @Anonymoose Good luck and have fun! Battlefield is a BOSS.